# How to find if cookie value match or not

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am reading cookie value for Cookie Consent "CookieScriptConsent" which can store values in different ways such as

```
{"action":"reject","categories":"[]"}

{"action":"accept","categories":"[]"}

{"action":"accept"}

{"action":"accept","categories":"[\"performance\",\"targeting\",\"functionality\"]","key":"58abddd4-493e-499a-9711-67644adc39af"}

{"action":"accept","categories":"[\"performance\"]","key":"24b56441-d831-4cd1-8e5f-47353257f500"}
```

I am using a cookie reading plugin which reads cookie value `Cookies.get('CookieScriptConsent');`

I store this value in variable and now i need to read values if cookie was accepted or rejected.

```
var string= Cookies.get('CookieScriptConsent');

var res = str.match(/accept/gi)
```

i am using `match` function of js to see if i find a match, it will return value or null how can i use this if if statement or what is the best way to achieve this

should i use `var n = str.indexOf("accept");` as it will give me numeric value which can easily be used in if statement to check if value is greater than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data stored in the cookie is a JSON object stringified, you can try to parse it and check if the property matches with the value you are looking for:

```
function getCookieData() {
    var cookie = Cookies.get("CookieScriptConsent");
    console.log("Raw data: ", cookie);
    if (cookie) {
        var scriptConsent = JSON.parse(cookie);
        if (scriptConsent.action === "accept") {
            console.log("Consented!");
        } else {
            console.log("Rejected!");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Cookie do not exists");
    }
}
```

This also allows you to check if this particular property has the value.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, This will work for part of json string but how ill i access `{"action":"accept","categories":"[\"performance\",\"targeting\",\"functionality\"]","key":"58abddd4-493e-499a-9711-67644adc39af"} ` for example if i want to know if user has accepted which category as options for this are store in array kind format can we access this or should i use simple match if  `performance` is there ....

Comment: If you have an array for the categories, you just can use any of the array helpers once the json is parsed, in the example: `scriptConsent.categories.indexOf("performance") > -1`. The `indexOf` function returns the index of the element witch you are looking for or `-1` if not found.